# Rails joint query with "like"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I read [on the official Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) how to make a joint query for a model `Client` which is associated to many `orders`. The code is the following

```
Client.joins(:orders).where(orders: {created_at: time_range})
```

and of course it works fine.

I'd like to modify the above inserting a LIKE query, something like

```
Client.joins(:orders).where(orders: {created_at: time_range, title: "LIKE Meeting"})
```

What is the right syntax to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
Client.joins(:orders).where("orders.created_at=? AND orders.title LIKE ? ", time_range, "Meeting")
```

Comment: You can use ILIKE for case insensitive if using postgres database

Comment: Also you can optionaly chain multiple where calls, each one will generate sql AND